# Serializers validation - TypeError... 'UniqueTogetherValidator' object is not iterable

Tags: django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model called 'following' where one user can follow another, using the Django rest framework. I am trying to implement a validation so that you can't follow someone twice, and trying the built-in UniqueTogetherValidator.

Here are the relevant parts of my models.py

```
class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='follower', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And serializers.py:

```
class FollowingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    follower = serializers.CharField(source='follower.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Following
        fields = ['user', 'follower']

        validators = UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset = Following.objects.all(),
            fields = ['user', 'follower'],
            message = "You are already following that person!"
        )
```

I have some existing data:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "user": "mike",
            "follower": "chelsea"
        },
        {
            "user": "mike",
            "follower": "chloe"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to add any new following object using the API interface, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /followings/
'UniqueTogetherValidator' object is not iterable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/followings/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'UniqueTogetherValidator' object is not iterable
...
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquetogethervalidator the `validators` variable under `Meta` should be a list,

your code should be

```
class FollowingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
user = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
follower = serializers.CharField(source='follower.username')

class Meta:
    model = Following
    fields = ['user', 'follower']

    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset = Following.objects.all(),
            fields = ['user', 'follower'],
            message = "You are already following that person!"
        )
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was reading a different page that had the syntax I wrote (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) but that makes a lot of sense.